# Por que no me muestra los stats del constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, printf

```
package Stats;

public class Players {
    private String name;
    private int RIT;
    private int TIR;
    private int PAS;
    private int REG;
    private int DEF;
    private int FIS;
    private int MED;

    public Players (String name, int RIT, int TIR, int PAS, int REG, 
    int DEF, int FIS, int MED) {
        this.name= name;
        this.RIT = RIT;
        this.TIR = TIR;
        this.PAS = PAS;
        this.REG = REG;
        this.DEF = DEF;
        this.FIS = FIS;
        MEDIA = MED;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Players player1 = new Players ("aa", 5,3,7,1,7,9,8);
        System.out.println(player1);
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando que me saque todas las variables del constructor con el println pero solo imprime "Stats.Players@14c3d7e" y si pongo println (name + "\n" + RIT + ....); dice que no se puede porque no es estatico.
Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puedes imprimir un objeto, y las propiedades no las podés leer directamente desde main porque éste es estático, y las propiedades son miembros del objeto.

Para hacer algo como lo que necesitás podrías hacerlo así:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Players player1 = new Players ("aa", 5,3,7,1,7,9,8);
    System.out.println(player1.name + "\n" + player1.RIT + ....);
}
```

De esta forma vas a imprimir las propiedades del objeto recién creado.

¡Suerte!